# Detect new app and run it in panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, detection

I am creating application that runs another app inside panel.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

public Form3() {
    InitializeComponent();

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Process p = Process.Start(@"path\app.exe");
    Thread.Sleep(200); // Allow the process to open it's window
    SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
}
```

But the problem is, that app.exe sometimes (I know when) creates new window as a new app. I want to add this new window into new panel.

```
private Process GetProcess() {
    //do some magic stuff and find actually running app
    return NewAppProcess;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Process p = GetProcess();
    SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel2.Handle);
}
```

Thanks for everything that can push me to right way

Comment: Watch `Win32_ProcessStartTrace`.

Comment: Making the UI of another process to be a child of your GUI is likely to freeze one or both apps.

Comment: Yeah i agree with @MickyD this is asking for trouble

Comment: @TheGeneral I'm not saying using `SetParent` is a good idea. But saying it makes the app freeze, is not really true. Take a look at the example which I shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`ManagementEventWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher.aspx), you can watch [`Win32_ProcessStartTrace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394374.aspx) to receive an event when a new process starts.

**Example**

In this example, I shows how you can watch starting of `mspaint.exe` and adding it as child of a `Panel` in your form. To so add a reference to `System.Management` dll to your project and then use the following code.

*Note 1:* The watcher is not super fast and you probably see the the window opens in desktop and then sits in the panel.

*Note 2:* It's an example and showing hot to do it with `mspaint.exe`. If you have any problem applying the solution on your real `app.exe`, you need to specifically ask about the solution for your `app.exe`.

*Note 3:* Make sure you run your as administrator.

```
using System.Management;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    ManagementEventWatcher watcher;
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(
            "Select * From Win32_ProcessStartTrace Where ProcessName = 'mspaint.exe'");
        watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
        watcher.Start();
    }
    void watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var id = (UInt32)e.NewEvent["ProcessID"];
        var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById((int)id);
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => {
            SetParent(process.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
        }));
    }
    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        watcher.Stop();
        watcher.Dispose();
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @MickyD It's rendered, you may need to move it to a location that you see it.

Comment: @MickyD See the screenshot.

Comment: Well blow me down.  OK  I found that I first had to setup Pain to start at the upper-left of my screen (near 0,0) so that when it is "embedded" it doesn't shoot of the right hand side of the WinForms app.  Surprisingly I was able to interact with Paint whilst embedded, much like you can with Ole.  Still....I think thar be dragons and it remains to be seen whether other apps play nice. ;)

Comment: Great soltuion. Works like a charm. Only problem is, that app was in full screen. Now is still in full screen but panel1 is little smaller, so i do not see everyting. But, I think, I can solve it. Many thanks :)